# How to animate a UIView partially offscreen

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimation

I have a rectangle UIView that sits at the bottom of its parent view (which is the full height and width of the screen) that I would like to animate down partially off of the screen after responding to an event. I have tried the following, but it just moves the origin up 100 and animates back to where it started:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, 
               delay: 1.2, 
               options: .curveEaseIn, 
               animations: {
                    self.subview.frame.origin.y += 100
                }, completion: {})
```

I've also tried setting a top constraint and changing that, but then it just squishes the view and it's children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This are the outlets

```
    @IBOutlet weak var topConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var testview: UIView!
```

Add this animation block where you want to animate on button action or user interaction.

```
self.topConstraint.constant += 100
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 5.0,
                   delay: 10,
                   options: .curveEaseIn,
                   animations: {
                    self.testview.layoutIfNeeded()
    }, completion: nil)
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Why you are using self.view? It should be your subview (rectangleView).

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, 
               delay: 1.2, 
               options: .curveEaseIn, 
               animations: {
                    self.subview.frame.origin.y += 100
                }, completion: {})
```

Comment: I am, I just changed the name of my view to obfuscate it for SO, but forgot that `self.view` was a thing. I'll edit my question to be clearer.